# Function and dependent variable are represented by the same symbol?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, notation

Is it wrong to represent a dependent variable and a function using the same symbol? For example, can we write the parametric equations of a curve in xy-plane as $x=x(t)$ , $y=y(t)$  where $t$  is the parameter? For me function is different from dependent variable.
But, in many calculus texts, sometimes, a dependent variable and a function are represented using the same symbol, why?

Comment: Technically, they are different, but writing this way is an acceptable "abuse of notation" because it saves on notational clutter.

Comment: Abuse of notation. Sometimes that's a good thing, sometimes bad. Different people have different opinions on when it's good and when bad.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494242/using-the-same-symbol-for-dependent-variable-and-function

Comment: If it's wrong then I don't wanna be right.

Comment: While $y=f(x)$ is a notation that conveys the verbal statement "$y$ is a $f$(unction) of $x$", sometimes the notation $y=y(x)$ is used in order to _stress_ the fact that $y$ is a function of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

When we write $y=f(x)$, we give names to the function, its input, and its output.

But  not all of these names are needed at all times.

- "let $f$ be a continuous function" names the function, but neither its input nor output.
- "$\langle\cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ is jointly continuous" is another version of the above.
- "$x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$  is an  increasing function" names the input, but neither the output nor the function. A less correct, but common  version of this statement omits   the "$x\mapsto $" part.

What if we want to give names to the input and output, but not to the function itself? Writing $y=\cdot (x)$ is typographically awkward. Writing $y=y(x)$ conveys as much information, and is less likely to be mistaken for a typo. I think  "$x\mapsto y$" would   be a better choice, but this is less common.